# How to use QtQuick.Controls 2.xx with QtGraphicalEffects

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a little problem with QtQuick controls 2 and graphical effects: as soon as I use a graphical effect on an item which contains a control (for instance a simple Button), the controls stop displaying correctly. For instance with a Button, only the text shows, the background is not visible anymore. It happens only with the Material style.

See the following example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Pane {
    id: root

    width: 300
    height: 150

    Pane {
        id: content
        visible: false
        width: 200
        height: 50

        Button {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "I'm a Button too..."
        }
    }

    DropShadow {
        anchors.fill: content
        source: content
        radius: 10
        samples: 21
    }

    Button {
        anchors.top: content.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        text: "Button"
    }
}
```

If you run this through qmlscene using the Material style (`qmlscene --style Material test.qml` where `test.qml` contains the previous example) then this is what happen:

[image]

The second button displays as it should, but the first one only show the text... As soon as I remove the DropShadow, the first button displays fine again.

Has anyone encountered this problem before ? Is this a known bug, or am I doing something I shouldn't ? Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

You declared your button as *flat* with the property `flat: true`. So, your button doesn't have a background.

The second problem is that you set the shadow on the `Pane` element and not the button. So, you will get somehting like this:

[image]

You can make your button filling the whole pane by adding the property `padding: 0`. Or, your can also remove the `Pane` and apply the shadow on the `Button`.

Comment: About the flat property, my mistake (I edited the sample in my question) but it doesn't change anything if I remove it: the background of the button is still not visible. As for the shadow, I **want** it to apply on the Pane, no the Button. The idea is to have a reusable "ShadowedPaned" that I can fill with whatever controls I want.

Comment: If you remove the `flat` property, your button should have its background. Try to clean and rebuild your project. Sometimes Qt Creator doesn't *see* the changes in qml files. If it does not work, you have a problem somewhere else and we need more info to help you (if I copy/paste your code in a new project, it works well)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but: No does not show, this is the whole point of the question. I didn't use QtCreator. Just run `qmlscene` on the sample I included in the question, it gives the result I included in the screenshot.

Comment: That's weird. I used qmlscene, too and I cannot see the problem. What is your Qt version?

Comment: Qt 5.12 on Windows. I forgot to mention that it happens only with Material style, sorry for the mix up. I'll edit the question. You need to run `qmlscene` with `-style=Material`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment: try running with `-style=Material`, the problem happens only with this style (forgot to mention that in the question, sorry for the inconvenience)

Comment: I don't have the Material style. What if you remove the property `visible: false` in your first Pane?

Comment: If I do that, the component will be rendered twice: once + once through the graphical effect. It's explicitly stated in most of the graphical effects components documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-dropshadow.html for instance) In the case of dropshadow, it probably shouldn't be problematic, but if I wanted to apply a `ColorOverlay` for instance, this wouldn't work.